# jenkins - give user premission to configure job

Tags: jenkins, authorization, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for a way to give users premission(authorization) to configure and build only the jobs they created and not every thing.

In the Matrix-based security in the job category the configure give premission for every job and its not something I want.

I only want to allow users to do thing on there own jobs

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this plug-ins solve your need

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

helpfull information:

[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2012/01/03/Allow+access+to+specific+projects+for+Users(Assigning+security+for+projects+in+Jenkins)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2012/01/03/Allow+access+to+specific+projects+for+Users%28Assigning+security+for+projects+in+Jenkins%29)

hope this would be helpfull for you @SH.IN

Comment: thanks its what I wanted , I dont know how I overlooked this one LOL